# SignalR auto disconnect event in SignalR - Angular 8

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, signalr

`I want to capture event of SignalR when the server is down and socket is disconnected. I could see it is getting logged but I am unable to capture and store the event.

Could anyone please let me know if there is any resolution`

[image: Logging is happening but unable to capture it]